# Get controller who has focus inside CWnd

Tags: c++, c, mfc

I've a dialog, CFormView, which holds some buttons and a panel which holds Tabcontrol, radiobuttons, text input fields etc.

So, on my panel, the CWnd, I create my input fields like this:

```
pEdit = new CEdit();
pEdit->CreateEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, _T("EDIT"), NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | nAttrMultiline | m_clRect, pclPanel, iID)
```

Where m_clRect is a CRect, pclPanel is my CWnd, and iID is just the controller ID.

I want to fill my `CEdit` with text when a button is clicked, but somehow I can't get the controller who has focus.

My first attempt was to call `GetFocus()`, cast it into a `CEdit` and add the text, but this just changes the text on my button, of course.

Second attempt was to check for `WM_SETFOCUS` with `ON_WM_SETFOCUS()` and keep the previous wnd and cast it and add text, but that just changes the text on my dialog.

Third attempt was to move this to my CWnd but as far as I can see, `WM_SETFOCUS` is never called.

Edit:

Tried `ON_WM_ACTIVATE` with `::OnActivate(UINT nState, CWnd* pWndOther, BOOL bMinimized)` inside my CWnd.
But that's not being called either.

Anybody has an idea what to try next?

Comment: pEdit->SetWindowText... GetFocus just retrieves the field that has the focus. In such a case the button. So it isn' helpful

Comment: Is that CEdit the only one in your window? If so, why not just keep that pointer around as a member, and then call its `SetWindowText()` when the button is clicked?

Comment: The CEdit is not the only one on the screen, the panel holds about 5-10. But I found a solution to my problem. I don't know if it's to use for anybody else though. But in OnCommand I can check for the EN_SETFOCUS and get my ID from wParam and get the controller from my ID.

Comment: You just answered yourself. The correct way to do it is: on the function that handles the `ON_COMMAND(...)` of each button call `pEdit->SetWindowText(_T("text"));`. `GetFocus()` is wrong, because it will return the button, as when you clicked it, you just finished to put the focus on it. You can get the edit using `CEdit* pEdit= ( CEdit*) GetDlgItem(ID_OF_EDIT);` where `ID_OF_EDIT` is the value you passed to `CreateEx` as `iId` parameter.

Comment: @sergiol Thank you, you should post that as an answer. More detailed than my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just answered yourself. The correct way to do it is: on the function that handles the

```
ON_COMMAND(...)
```

of each button call

```
pEdit->SetWindowText(_T("text"));.
```

`GetFocus()` is wrong, because it will return the button, as when you clicked it, you just finished to put the focus on it. You can get the edit using

```
CEdit* pEdit= ( CEdit*) GetDlgItem(ID_OF_EDIT);
```

where `ID_OF_EDIT` is the value you passed to `CreateEx` as `iId` parameter.